# ASP.NET MVC + Entity - Como mapear novas tabelas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, code-first

Bom dia,

Tenho um projeto utilizando `ASP.MVC` + `EF` e mapiei cerca de 20 tabelas usando o assistente do VS (criando o `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`, selecionando a base de dados e as tabelas que quero), mas agora tenho mais 16 tabelas para inserir no sistema e não encontro uma opção para inclui-las utilizando o mapeamento automático (como nas primeiras 20).

Pelo que vi, algumas pessoas indicam excluir a minha classe que possui os `DbContext` (criada a partir do assistente do `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`) e recria-la, mas não tenho certeza se esse é o caminho ideal, visto que os models do inicio já estão formatados com `Data Annotations` e são usados em diversos controllers.

**Existe alguma forma de mapear novas tabelas usando o Wizard do `Entity Data Model` sem a necessidade de excluir o `DBContext` criado no primeiro mapeamento?**

*Estou usando o Visual Studio Community 2017 e o modo Code First from DataBase.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode abrir o designer clicando com o botão direito do mouse no seu arquivo *.EDMX* e selecionando *Open With -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model Designer*
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Clique com o botão direito na superfície de designer do designer `.EDMX` e clique em `Update Model From Database`.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Todas as entidades são atualizadas por padrão, as novas entidades só são adicionadas se você as selecionar.

Comment: Olá, Marconcilio Souza! Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

No caso que citei acima, não tenho .EDMX pois usei o EF Code First from Database - pelo que pesquisei, o EDMX é gerado quando utiliza-se o Designer Centric (Model First e DataBase First).

De qualquer forma, para resolver o meu problema criei os models na mão. Talvez não tenha sido a forma mais agil, mas consegui aprender alguns concetos importantes que não tinha notado até então.

Muito obrigado pela sua disponibilidade em ajudar! Abraço!